# customize paypal integration in php html javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, paypal, payment

a site i am working on requires to have an option to pay with paypal and another through direct billing. 
I though the shopping cart would lead to a payment method and depending on the payement option selected either the user will be sent the bill via email or rerouted to paypal to complete the payment.
I was wondering if anyone knows what link should I reroute to and what parameters should i include and how.
thank you so much for your help in advance

Comment: check the PayPal API. Did you try Googling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_landing